# How to Save Captured Picture into SQLite as blob and Retrieve back in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a created Phonegap Project that captures a Picture using Camera following the tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/phonegap/phonegap-from-scratch-camera-exporting/.Now I want to save the image as blob into a sqlite database. Also once saved retrieve and display the image. Please suggest.

Comment: Hi Priya your issue is solved ?

Comment: @Priya: Have you got the working code for this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

**Please follow below step** 
**1.** Get Your picture as base 64 using phone gap Camera API 
**2.** Now convert Base 64 to Blob object

```
function convertDataURIToBlob(dataURI, mimetype) {
    var BASE64_MARKER= ';base64,';
    var base64Index = dataURI.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
    var base64 = dataURI.substring(base64Index);  
    var raw = window.atob(base64);
    var rawLength = raw.length;
    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);   
    }
    var bb = new BlobBuilder();
    bb.append(uInt8Array.buffer);
    return bb.getBlob(mimetype); 
}
```

Instead of passing in a mimetype though, you should extract it from
the data url and use that with getBlob().
OR 
use this [plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Canvas-to-Blob) 

**3.** Now you can save your image using phonegap Storage API to Sqlite your desired column data type is string.
**4.** Fetch your blob object from Sqlite using Phone gap Storage API 
**5.** Now represent this object to HTMl tag using Java script.Here 
  sample blob object to HTML 5

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>    
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8" />    
    <title>Blob</title>    
    <script type="text/javascript">    
        (function () {    
            window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;    
            function contentLoaded() {    
                var blob = new Blob(['alert("hello")'], { type: 'text/javascript' });    
                var script = document.createElement('script');    
                script.setAttribute('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));    
                document.body.appendChild(script);    
            }    
            window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', contentLoaded, false);    
        } ());    
    </script>    
</head>    
<body>    
    <div id="container">    
    </div>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: How to get mimetype ?